# jQuery - enable/disable select box within a toggle();

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have an instance where I want to change the text and the status of a select box based on a click.

```
$("#foo").click(function(){

 $("#mytext").toggle();
 $(this).text($(this.text() == 'on' ? 'off' : 'on');
 // here i also want to enable and disable a select box, not sure how to do this other   then checking if the value of (this).text is on or off.

});
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var status = $(this).text();

$('#dropdownId').prop('disabled',status != 'on');
```